# Magento Shopping Cart Price Rules Wrong Calculation

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

I am running a $10 off coupon code for orders over $100 and more.

When there's one SKU in cart, the code works perfectly fine.

When there's multiple SKU in cart, the code fails.

Here's my settings

Conditions:
**If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Subtotal  equals or greater than  100**

Actions:
**Apply: fixed amount discount for whole cart

Discount Amount: 10

Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 0

Discount Qty Step (Buy X): 0

Apply to Shipping Amount: No

Free Shipping: No

Stop Further Rules Processing: Yes**

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in ver 1.9.0.1

http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/67

You can check workaround at [GitHub](https://github.com/husseycoding/cartrulefix). Have not tried it myself, though lots of users reported it useful.